# How to avoid resizing of UITableView inside UiNavigationcontroller which is inside a custom container(stackedViewcontroller)

Tags: ipad, uitableview, ios5, uinavigationcontroller, screen-orientation

```
MoveToNewLocViewContoller *move2NewLocVC = [[MoveToNewLocViewContoller alloc] initWithLocItemArray:moveToNewLocArray andSyLocIDArray:syLocIdArray];
        [move2NewLocVC setTitle:cell.textLabel.text];


        UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:move2NewLocVC];
        navController.view.width = PSIsIpad() ? self.view.width : 100;
        [navController.navigationBar setTintColor:BLUE];


        if (navController) {

            [XAppDelegate.menuInterfaceViewController.stackViewController pushViewController:navController fromViewController:nil animated:YES];
            [navController release];
            //[viewController release];
            [moveToNewLocArray release];
            [move2NewLocVC release];
        }
```

Now I want the Navigation Controller above to not resize when I rotate my ipad. I have tried 
    navController.view.autoresizesSubviews = NO;

This works, but there is a catch it doesn't allow my UITableView(MoveToNewLocViewController) to scroll till the bottom. The main purpose of avoiding resizing is to avoid redrawing my huge custom UITableViewcell to fit the orientation. I know I have to resize my UiTableview after the orientation but the question is where. I tried

```
 -(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {}

-(void) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {}
```

It doesn't seem to work. Is this because I am inserting it to a stacked container view?

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by including the UITableView inside the UIView which is then added to the UiNavigationController as UIViewController. When the device rotates the I resize the view in the didRotateFrominterfaceOrientation Method

```
-(void) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:  (UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
  PSStackedViewController *stackController = XAppDelegate.menuInterfaceViewController.stackViewController;
if( [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){
    [stackController setLargeLeftInset:50 animated:YES];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake(self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.origin.x, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height);
    self.move2NewLocTableView.height = self.view.height;
}
if( [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
    //self.navigationController.view.frame = self.tableView.frame;
    [stackController setLargeLeftInset:320 animated:YES];
    self.move2NewLocTableView.height = 700;
}
```